# Dice-rolling game doesn't change results

Tags: python

Doing a dice Rolling game in python, and whenever I start my second round I still end up getting the same dice results from the previous round.

```
import random
import time

#gets the dice side
def roll_dice(sides):
    dice_results = list()
    for side in sides:
        roll_result = random.randint(1,side+1)
        dice_results.append(roll_result)
    return dice_results

#pulls a dice out from the list
def dice_fell(roll_result):  
    player1_dice = player1_dice_results
    player2_dice = player2_dice_results

    for item in player1_dice:
        if item % 4 == 0:
            player1_dice.remove(item)
        return player1_dice

    for item in player2_dice:
        if item % 4 == 0:
            player2_dice.remove(item)
            return player2_dice
# variables 

dice_set1=[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100]
dice_set2=[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100]

player1_dice_results = roll_dice(dice_set1)
player2_dice_results = roll_dice(dice_set2)

player1_final_results = dice_fell(player1_dice_results)
player2_final_results = dice_fell(player2_dice_results)

player1_total= sum(player1_dice_results)
player2_total= sum(player2_dice_results)

player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0

while player1_score < 3 or player2_score < 3:
# This part just announces what happens 

    exit= input(str("Press Enter to start! Press 'q' to leave after each round! \n"))
    if exit != "q":
        print("Let's begin! Be careful for the small table!")
    elif exit == "q":
        quit()

    print("You are rolling...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You have rolled: ",player1_final_results)

    if len(player1_final_results) < 7:
        print("Sorry player 1, some of your dice have fallen off the table!")

    print()
    print("Your total is: ",player1_total)
    print()

    print("Player 2 is rolling...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Player 2 has rolled:" ,player2_final_results)
    if len(player2_final_results) < 7:
        print("Sorry player 2, some of your dice have fallen off the table!")
    print()
    print("Player 2's total is: ",player2_total)
    print()

    if player1_total > player2_total:
        print()
        print("You have won the round with,",player1_total,"!"),
        player1_score += 1
        print("Your score is: ",player1_score)
    elif player2_total > player1_total:
        print()
        print("Player 2 has won the round with,",player2_total,"!"),
        player2_score += 1
        print("Player 2's score is: ",player2_score)

    if player1_score == 3:
        print("Congratulations, you won!")
    elif player2_score == 3:
        print("Player 2 wins! Better luck next time champ!")
```

Comment: _"This part just annouces what happens "_ Where does it do that? I don't see it printing any information about the dice rolls. If I paste all this code into one script and run it, will I see the problem you're describing?

Comment: Added the rest of it. Had to break it up some so I could submit it. Sorry about that!

Comment: Please read [mcve] and spend more time on the layout; nobody wants to comb through a poorly-formatted code dump.

Comment: It's very hard to give advice without being able to replicate the problem, but try putting the dice rolling code inside the loop. If you only ever roll the dice once, then it will never change value.

Comment: There's a lot of indentation errors here for anyone who wants to try the code out for themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I've fixed the indentation problems.
I *have* reproduced the problem.
As Kevin said, your immediate problem is that you roll the dice only once, *before* you enter your **while** loop.  Here's what it looks like with the rolls inside the loop, but after the player decides whether to continue.

```
dice_set1=[4,6,8,10,12,20,100]
dice_set2=[4,6,8,10,12,20,100]

player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0

while player1_score < 3 or player2_score < 3:
    # This part just announces what happens

    exit = raw_input(str("Press Enter to start! Press 'q' to leave after each round! \n"))
    if exit != "q":
        print("Let's begin! Be careful for the small table!")
    elif exit == "q":
        quit()

    player1_dice_results = roll_dice(dice_set1)
    player2_dice_results = roll_dice(dice_set2)

    player1_final_results = dice_fell(player1_dice_results)
    player2_final_results = dice_fell(player2_dice_results)

    player1_total= sum(player1_dice_results)
    player2_total= sum(player2_dice_results)

    print("You are rolling...")
    ... # remainder of code omitted
```

---

That said, do note that you have several other problems with the program.  You won't terminate until *both* players have won three times -- use **and** instead of **or** in the **while** condition.

Most of my other comments are more appropriate for the codeReview group; you might post there when you're done debugging.

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb now, this worked. Thanks for all the help Prune and Kevin!